# Nvidia driver v.384 has some problems with 4.10.0-32 kernel

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kernel, kubuntu

So I'm using Kubuntu 17.04 and it was working perfectly until I upgraded Nvidia from v.381 to v.384. The grub automatically uses kernel 4.10.0-32 to boot and after the "kubuntu splash screen" (before boot - the one with kubuntu logo and glowing light behind it) it only shows a blinking cursor ( _ ). when I try to boot with 4.10.0-19 it boot to Kubuntu and every thing works fine. I tried and uninstalled all Nvidia packages and the problem didn't occur again. so I reproduced the bug with installing the 384 again and the now the same thing happens, so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the kernel version. if anyone has any solutions to this I'd really appreciate it.

[ also I'm not an expert in Linux and have been using it for a few months. ]

Comment: Well, if it is - i seriously doubt it because I had the same driver version running with the same kernel - it no longer matters because 4.10.0-32 has been superseded.

Answer (score 0):

the nvidia-384 driver is braking Qt-quick ,,see

https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2017/08/warning-nvidia-driver-384-69-seems-to-be-broken-with-qtquick/

downgrade to the 381 and stay their for a wile .

VINNY
VINNY@ https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum.php